# Length of composition series of a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ be an $n$-dimensional commutative $k$-algebra. I have a vague recollection of the following fact, of which I am no longer sure:

> $A$ has a composition series of *ideals* of length $n$.

Certainly, $A$ is an Artinian ring and has a composition series of $A$-submodules (=ideals) of length $\leq n$. As a $k$-module (i.e. vector space), $A$ has a composition series of $k$-submodules of length $n$ (=dimension of the $k$-vector space). Obviously, each $A$-submodule is a $k$-submodule, but not vice versa.

> Is it true that one can always find among the $k$-submodules a strict chain of $A$-submodules of length $n$?

I'd appreciate a reference or a self-contained (dis)proof.

Comment: Take $A$ to be a finite filed extension of $k$ of degree $n$ for a counter example.

Comment: @Mohan: oh, indeed. Thanks for setting me straight.